# Why does PS Remote play Apple Script code only work occasionally

Tags: macos, applescript

I have very little programming knowledge but I am trying to make a code that follows a certain pattern of down arrows and returns in PS Remote play. I have written the following code and it works about a quarter of the time but other times it skips a step or two. Does anyone know what is going wrong with the code? Any help would be appreciated thanks. I am on macOS Big Sur

```
tell application "RemotePlay" 
repeat 300 times
    activate
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events" to key code 125
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events" to key code 125
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events" to key code 36
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events" to key code 125
    delay 3
    tell application "System Events" to key code 36
    
    delay 60
end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Your code is fine. (You could clean it up a bit, for instance by having one tell System Events block with all the key codes and delays inside). However, UI scripting is quirky and unreliable in many instances. Really the only thing to try is increasing the delay times.

Comment: @jweaks: depending on what he's trying to do in the game, the delay might be too *long*. if this is supposed to access some onscreen menu, more time might be needed for each new graphic element to appear. But if this is supposed to mimic some combination of movements, it may be too slow, with the system resetting itself before it completes. More information is necessary.